# Optimizing join query to fetch data from A with condition on B sorted by B

Tags: mysql, join

I have an item-to-item similarity matrix set up with these tables:

```
items (id, ...) (Primary key `id`)
similarities (item1_id, item2_id, similarity) (Index on `item1_id` and `item2_id`)
```

The `similarities` tables contains pairs of ids with a similarity index, i.e:

```
item1_id  item2_id  similarity
1         2         0.3143
2         3         0.734
```

For efficient storage "reverse pairs" are omitted, i.e. there's only one pair (1,2), there's no redundant pair (2,1). That means the foreign key for an item may be either `item1_id` or `item2_id`.

Now I want to find items that are similar to a bunch of other items, sorted by descending similarity. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT    `Item`.*
FROM      `items` AS `Item`
LEFT JOIN `similarities` AS `Similarity`
       ON (`Item`.`id` = `Similarity`.`item1_id`
              AND `Similarity`.`item2_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...))
          OR (`Item`.`id` = `Similarity`.`item2_id`
              AND `Similarity`.`item1_id` IN (1, 2, ,3, ...))
WHERE     `Similarity`.`item1_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
          OR `Similarity`.`item2_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
GROUP BY  `Item`.`id`
ORDER BY  `Similarity`.`similarity` desc
```

It's extremely slow though, it takes 4-5 seconds for ~100,000 items and ~30,000 similarity pairs. It seems the JOIN is extremely costly. Here's the query `EXPLAIN`ed:

```
select_type  table       type         possible_keys      key                key_len  ref   rows    Extra
SIMPLE       Similarity  index_merge  item1_id,item2_id  item1_id,item2_id  110,110  NULL  31      Using sort_union(item1_id,...
SIMPLE       Item        ALL          PRIMARY            NULL               NULL     NULL  136600  Using where; Using join buffer
```

What can I do to speed this up? Worst case I would do it in two separate queries, but I'd prefer one JOIN query if possible.

Comment: I really wanted to answer this question, in return for your help. Since clicking through, I don't think I can. Good luck!

Comment: Is "a bunch of other items" represented by (1,2,3,...) ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Lester Yes, these are the ids of a bunch of items I want to fetch similar items for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't actually try this but maybe it points you in the right direction. The idea is to make a temp result of the `UNION` of (unique) id, similarity pairs from `similarities`, then join items with that.

```
SELECT Item.*, s.other_item_id, s.similarity
FROM items AS Item
JOIN
    (
    SELECT item1_id AS id, item2_id AS other_item_id, similarity FROM similarities
    UNION
    SELECT item2_id AS id, item1_id AS other_item_id, similarity FROM similarities
    ) AS s ON s.id = items.id
WHERE items.id IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
ORDER BY s.similarity DESC;
```

In your original query you don't need to restrict the ids from `similarities` in both the `JOIN` condition and the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So basically my two-seperate-queries strategy rolled into one query? :) I'll give this a try. I have to see if how to push this through my DAL though.

Comment: It would help if you can give an example of the desired result. Do you want to see the other item ID a given item is similar to?

Comment: I only want the records of the items, like a normal `SELECT * FROM items`. The similarity is only the condition, I don't need to fetch it. In fact, I'll probably be using a `LIMIT` to only fetch a number of "top similar" items. You could describe the query as "Find 10 items that are most similar to these items (1, 2, 3, ...)."

Comment: OK... so you will have a WHERE condition that limits the result to similarity in a specific range or something?

Comment: Comment timing overlap... :) It'll be a `LIMIT`ed query, hence the sorting. Also, similarities of 0 are omitted in the matrix, so as long as there *is* a similarity and it's sorted in descending order, that's fine.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure my solution gets exactly what you want but maybe it points you to another way to do the join without so many conditions. You could make a VIEW from the UNION'd SELECTs, or a temp table if similarities doesn't change often and you need to run a lot of queries against it.

Comment: Hmm, overall the query is about as slow as my original one, since it still requires a ginormous JOIN...

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering whether joining to the items table twice will perform better than the two queries.
Pardon the psuedo-code-ish SELECT portion of this statement - I think you'll actually need a CASE for every field value...

```
SELECT    
CASE WHEN `Item2`.`id` IS NULL THEN 
  `Item1`.`id`
ELSE `Item2`.`id`
END,

SELECT    
CASE WHEN `Item2`.`id` IS NULL THEN 
  `Item1`.`name`
ELSE `Item2`.`name`
END,

SELECT    
CASE WHEN `Item2`.`id` IS NULL THEN 
  `Item1`.`description`
ELSE `Item2`.`description`
END,

[and so on]

FROM      `items` AS `Item1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `similarities` AS `Similarity`
       ON (`Item1`.`id` = `Similarity`.`item1_id`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `items` AS `Item2`
       ON (`Item2`.`id` = `Similarity`.`item2_id`       
WHERE     `Similarity`.`item1_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
          OR `Similarity`.`item2_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
ORDER BY  `Similarity`.`similarity` desc
```

Comment: Uuh, funky, thanks! :) I'm getting a syntax error on the `CASE` statement within the `SELECT` statement though. Just testing with `SELECT Item1.*, Item2.*` gives blazingly fast results though. I'll have to play around with this more. Would be happy if you could improve this as well.

Comment: Testing with `CASE WHEN Item2.id IS NULL THEN Item1.id ELSE Item2.id END CASE` gives me a syntax error near `CASE FROM ...` (the `END CASE` statement) BTW.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it a bit.  Separate CASE for each field name (this is only so that your new query contains the same # of fields as your old one, since you mentioned an existing DAL already.)

Comment: I ended up with a different solution, but your answer gave me some inspiration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the inspirations, I ended up with this query:

```
SELECT `Item`.*
FROM `items` AS `Item`
JOIN (
    SELECT `item1_id` AS `id`, `similarity`
    FROM   `similarities`
    WHERE  `similarities`.`item2_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
    UNION
    SELECT `item2_id` AS `id`, `similarity`
    FROM   `similarities`
    WHERE  `similarities`.`item1_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
) AS `SimilarityUnion` ON `SimilarityUnion`.`id` = `Item`.`id`
GROUP BY `SimilarityUnion`.`id`
ORDER BY `SimilarityUnion`.`similarity` DESC
```